# How to verify from CLI that Magento was installed successfully?

Tags: magento2, installation, cli

I'm running the `setup:install` command in an automation script to perform the initial Magento installation. How to determine in another script (POSIX `sh`) that the previous run of this command has been finished successfully? I want to determine whether it was installed successfully or not to retry the installation from scratch if the installation was incomplete. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but maybe it helps! First Magento displays the following commands to the console

```
Post installation file permissions check...
For security, remove write permissions from these directories: '/var/www/html/magento2/app/etc'
[Progress: 274 / 274]
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Admin Panel URI: /admin_xxxxxx
```

After a successful installation you can create an admin user using the `admin:user:create` command: Maybe you can verify if this succeeds?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it makes sense. But I'm currently creating the admin user by the `setup:install` parameters `--admin-user "$ADMIN_LOGIN" --admin-password "$ADMIN_PASSWORD"`. Can I add another admin user for test purposes by the `admin:user:create` command?

Comment: You have the option to install Magento without creating the Magento administrator user as shown in the following example.

magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com \
--elasticsearch-port=9200 or you can create multiple admin users.